# [bash]how can I add timestamp to ftp transferred files

Tags: bash, ftp, timestamp

my bash script get a txt file, composed with username and password, scans it a connect by ftp to a host with those credentials.

then it attempts to do some ncftpput. I want to add to the transferred files the date of creation of them.

how can I do that?

```
PSEUDOCODE

while read a b{
      ncftpput -u $a -p $b hostFTP $folder_src $folder_dest
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with `ncftpput`, but you can use the `date` command to get a timestamp:

```
TIME_STAMP=`date +"%Y%m%d_%H%M%S"`
# Becomes something like 20130219_115000
```

Simply use the `$TIME_STAMP` variable as a part of the resulting filename.

Comment: I think this could be a way, but how can I add that timestamp to every files implicated into trasfer?

Comment: You would have to modify the filenames before they get sent. That would require an extra processing step before your `while` loop. From the documentation I see on `ncftpput`, there's no way to get it to append or prepend a name to each file that gets sent.

Comment: To my limited knowledge, that is correct. That said, it wouldn't surprise me if there was a tool out there that could handle this kind of operation.

Comment: can I make a copy of the file with the same name added with $timestamp?

Comment: Sure. Just make sure to clean it up after the transfer. Better yet, just rename the file, transfer it, and restore the filename.